# Postman Execute a part of the code if one or more tests fails

Tags: javascript, json, postman

Im doing a workflow in Postman right now and got an issue...

I got e.g. 2 Requests and i want to execute them, but the second
Request should just start if  in the first request none of the
post-script tests fails, otherwise the first request should be executed
again.

I am aware of `postman.setNextRequest("AddAccountForTesting");`and i already got the first request to loop itself, but i dont know how i can check if a test in the first request fails...

Hope someone can help